# Value always being returned as zero?

Tags: c++, loops, return, do-while

I have to write a loop that performs some mathematical function and accumulates an answer as you go. But for some reason, currentNum, my return value, is being returned as 0 all the time. I tried declaring currentNum as some num in the switch statement thinking it would work since currentNum is a global statement, but it also returned zero; so I tried this and this also returned zero? Also, how do I return -1? When I return -1, the console states the program returned 255 instead of -1.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int accumulate(double currentNum, double num, char op);

char op, x, X;
double currentNum, num;

int main(){ 

    do{
    cout << "Current: " << currentNum << endl;

    cout << "Next operation: ";
    cin >> op;

    if(!(op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')){
        cout << "Invalid operation!";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Next Number: ";
    cin >> num;

    accumulate(currentNum, num, op);

    }while(op != x || op != X);
}

int accumulate(double currentNum, double num, char op){
    switch(op){
        case '+':
            currentNum = currentNum+num;
            return currentNum;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            currentNum = currentNum-num;
            return currentNum;
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case '*':
            currentNum = currentNum*num;
            return currentNum;
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case '/':
            currentNum = currentNum/num;
            return currentNum;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        default:
            // If the operator is other than +, -, * or /, error message is shown
            cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the signature to take `currentNum` by reference: `int accumulate(double& currentNum, double num, char op){`

Comment: @user0042 Thanks for the reply, can I ask what the & or * would do?

Comment: `currentNum` is a `double` and you're function returns an `int`.

Comment: You should assign the returned value to `currentNum`.

Comment: You should also initialise your variables.

Comment: Yes you call the function but never use its returned value. Try: `currentNum = accumulate(currentNum, num, op);`

Comment: @Vincent The `&` means that the variable is taken by reference and may be changed within the function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass references of numbers to accumulate function.

int accumulate(double & currentNum, double & num, char op);

use the same syntax while defining accumulate fucntion.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should get clearer about what is the meaning of "return". The returning value doesn't mean that it is the value that is changed. It means that the function can be treated as this value if you want to.

---

For example when you are writing a function

```
int foo(int a)
```

which doubles *a* and then use it in your main function

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    foo(a);
    cout << a;
}
```

you will get 1 instead of 2.

But if you change the line

```
foo(a);
```

into

```
a = foo(a);
```

you will get 2.

To change a value inside a function you should pass it by reference or pointer. That is, the definition would be like

```
void foo(int &a)   /   void foo(int *a)
```